# Easiest way to create a formatting-rich plot label?

Tags: output-formatting

How can I make a formatting-rich label and put in on a 2D plot? Example:

[image: Output example]

Please note superscripts, different colors and a need to avoid evaluating the expression.

Comment: `x = 4; y = 5; Plot[Sin[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotLabel ->   TraditionalForm[ Style[HoldForm[x^3], Blue, 32] + Style[HoldForm[y^3], Red, 32]]]`?

Answer (score 7):

[`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html#) may help with keeping the symbols unevaluated.

A quick example may be something like this:

```
Plot[Sin[x] + Sin[2 x^6], {x, -2, 2}, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style[HoldForm[Sin[x]] 
+ Style[HoldForm[Sin[2 x^.2]], Bold, Red], 
Blue]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to  use MateX, and the math also looks better :)

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{xcolor}"}]
label=MaTeX[
      "\\textcolor{blue}{\\sin(x)}+\\textcolor{red}{\\sin\\left( 2 x^{0.2} \\right)}",
      Magnification->2]
```

Now

```
  Plot[Sin[x]+Sin[2 x^6],{x,-2,2},PlotLabel->label]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can go a little fancy and box it

```
label=MaTeX[
"\\boxed{\\textcolor{blue}{\\sin(x)}+\\textcolor{red}{\\sin\\left( 2 x^{0.2} \\right)}}",
   Magnification->1.5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And little more fancy and color the box also

```
label=MaTeX[
"\\color{magenta}\\boxed{\\textcolor{blue}{\\sin(x)}+\\textcolor{red}{\\sin\\left( 2 x^{0.2} \\right)}}",
   Magnification->2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I am not good in coloring, so may be there is better color for the frame.

Comment: Thank you, Nasser! MaTeX is really good for beautifying. And self-explanatory as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just type it as usual. Type `"x"`, select the x, press Command - Shift - T to convert it to traditional form, then type and format as you normally would. See the Format menu and the usual shortcuts for typing math.