# How can I blur/remove the borderline around text?

Tags: functions, function-construction

How can I make the borderline around the LaTeX expressions below more blurry, or can I remove it with some setting?

```
myfunc = {ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2 x], x >= 1 || x <= 0],
   ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x >= 0],
   ConditionalExpression[2 - x, x <= 1]};
MaTeX[TextForm[#]] & /@ myfunc
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** Working with `TeXForm`s of `ConditionalExpression`s in  `myfunc` to construct strings to pass to `MaTeX`:

```
texForms = ToString @* TeXForm /@ myfunc
```

> ```
> {"\\fbox{$| 1-2 x| \\text{ if }x\\geq 1\\lor x\\leq 0$}", 
> "\\fbox{$x+1\\text{ if }x\\geq 0$}", "\\fbox{$2-x\\text{ if }x\\leq 1$}"}
> ```

To remove the frame, we simply take the substring between `$`s inside `\fbox`:

```
MaTeX[First@StringCases["$" ~~ a___ ~~ "$" :> a]@#,  Magnification -> 3] &/@ texForms //
  Column
```

[image]

To modify the frame, we use the function `ceTeXForm` to inject the needed LaTeX commands into the strings:

```
ceTeXForm = StringReplace[{"if" -> "\\textcolor{red!50}{if}", 
    "\\fbox" -> "\\setlength{\\fboxrule}{3pt}\n\\fcolorbox{gray!20}{white}"}];


SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{xcolor}"}];

MaTeX[ceTeXForm @ #, Magnification -> 2] & /@ texForms
```

[image]

```
MaTeX[ceTeXForm @ #, Magnification -> 4] & @ 
 "\\fbox{$| \\beta z + \\alpha \\sqrt w| \\text{ if }\\sin (x)\\leq \\cos ^2(y)$}"
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use the option `DisplayFunction` in `TemplateBox` to override the option setting inherited from `StyleDefinitions` for `"ConditionalExpression"`:

```
ClearAll[removeCEFrame]
removeCEFrame[ce_ConditionalExpression] := RawBoxes @ 
   ReplaceAll[
    TemplateBox[a_, "ConditionalExpression", c___] :> 
     TemplateBox[a, "ConditionalExpression", 
      DisplayFunction :> (RowBox[{#1, 
           StyleBox[" if ", ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
            FontFamily -> "Roboto-Medium", FontOpacity -> 0.44], #2}] &), c]] @
   ToBoxes[ce]
```

***Example:***

```
myfunc
```

[image]

```
removeCEFrame /@ myfunc
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can modify the frame style:

```
ClearAll[modifyCEFrame]
modifyCEFrame[style_ : None][ce_ConditionalExpression] := RawBoxes @ 
  ReplaceAll[
    TemplateBox[a_, "ConditionalExpression", c___] :> 
     TemplateBox[a, "ConditionalExpression", 
      DisplayFunction :> (FrameBox[
        RowBox[{#1, StyleBox[" if ", ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
          FontFamily -> "Roboto-Medium", FontOpacity -> 0.44], #2}], 
        FrameStyle -> style, RoundingRadius -> 4, BaselinePosition -> Baseline] &), c]]@
   ToBoxes[ce]]
```

***Examples:***

```
modifyCEFrame[] /@ myfunc
```

[image]

```
modifyCEFrame[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[.1], Red]] /@ myfunc
```

[image]

```
modifyCEFrame[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], GrayLevel[.8]]] /@ myfunc
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible to make the bolderline of the result of this `MaTeX[modifyCEFrame[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[.1]]] /@ 
  myfunc]` blur as well?  It works without outside `MaTeX` but when I wrap it around `MaTeX` the it doesn't work. Not sure if this is related to `MaTeX` instead. 
Remove the boderline work well for `MaTeX`.

Comment: I tried this but the result is same `MaTeX[modifyCEFrame[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], GrayLevel[.9]]] /@
   myfunc]`

Comment: @hana, not sure if `MaTeX`, by default, handles colored text and frames. See   [this answer by Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162024/125) for ways to color text and frames.

Comment: thanks, that looks nice

Comment: @hana, pls see the update.

Comment: thanks, that looks very nice.